# How to obtain statistical information from a Likert scale with a sample size smaller than the number of questions?

Tags: factor-analysis, likert, reliability, small-sample, validity

**Research and sample properties**

I'm measuring the degree of a certain concept related to marketing and sustainable development throughout an entire industry. The theoretical model is depicted next:
[image: Theoretical model]

The concepts M1,M2 and M3 build an existing scale (containing 20 items in total), that in addition with S1, S2 and S3 (29 items) are the antecedents of the latent variable desired to measure. There also 2 concepts (PM and OL) representing the consequences of the Latent Variable (10 items in total), with the dependant relation showed in the figure. This being so, a 5-point Likert-based scale was developed (summing all mentioned items, total of 59), also adding company size data (annual production, workers, etc). The sample contains 45 answers from companies' managers (n=45) of a 120 companies industry.

**Questions**

(1) How can I perform a reliability, validity and scale reduction (with Factor Analysis) analysis with a sample size smaller than the number of questions? (since the industry has a small number of companies, increasing the sample is not an option) When I try to do these procedures on SPSS, the correlation matrix is not positive-definite.

(2) How can I analyze the relations between antecedents and consequences with the latent variable? Maybe the 6 elements of antecedents can be represented as factor, but what happens with consequences?

(3) How can I weigh the responses with each company's data (production, for example)? This is an important issue being some companies are way bigger than others.

(4) Finally, how can I measure the "degree of" the latent variable with all the data collected? (there's no quantitative research on the matter, so there's no parameters to establish a high or low level of the concept).

Comment: Just a few questions/comments that come to mind: (1) Do you really want a formative and not a reflective model for the LV? (2) Do you need the LV at all, or could M1 - S3 directly influence PM? (3) Parceling may reduce the number of variables but is not without debate. (4) Factor score regression (Croon, 2002) seems to work well in small samples (see https://dx.doi.org/10.1177/0013164415607618). (5) The model is too complex for n=45, you either have to make it simpler or get more data.